# Listview throws Canvas trying to draw too large(112896000bytes) bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, out-of-memory, listviewitem

I am using an `listview` inside a horizontal `scrollview` and it works well for large screen devices but when it comes to mobile `listview` adapter is showing Canvas: trying to draw too large(112896000bytes) bitmap error. I have provided my main and `listview` adapter `xml` files.

**My main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/headerheight"
    android:background="#dc5E4485"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingLeft="3sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_tableView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:text="Next" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width_min"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:background="@drawable/thin_line_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Select"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width_min"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".31"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="S.No"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!--<ListView
            android:id="@+id/inventoryItemList1"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".09"
            android:background="@drawable/thin_line_border"
            android:divider="@null">

        </ListView>-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save_tableView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/thick_line_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Save" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableviewlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"

      android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="Charge Reading"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView9"

     android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="30 Min"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView10"

     android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="1.00 Hr"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/inventoryItemList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".09"
                    android:divider="@null"></ListView>



        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Listview adapter layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/assetTitleLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/tableList1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            />

        <EditText
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/tableList2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            />

        <EditText
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/tableList3"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:text=""
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:id="@+id/tableList4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/tableList5"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

            <EditText
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:id="@+id/tableList6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

            <EditText
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:id="@+id/tableList7"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />

            <EditText
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:id="@+id/tableList8"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tableList9"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            />
        <EditText
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tableList10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/column_width"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button_ghost"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try loading the images with Glide , as the image you are using is large in size

Comment: Move your image in the (hi-res) drawable to drawable-xxhdpi. But in app development, you not need to use to large image its increase your APK file size.

Comment: also go through this https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Use Picasso for image loading and caching.This will not consume memory and your app will not lag while scrolling. visit: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Problem was not in my main view it was in adapter view there i thought of using white color as background instead i used an jpg image as a background

Comment: @Dilip did you solve the problem? I am facing same issue.